# How to put several values in one row when use reshape in R?

Tags: r, reshape

I have a frame with this format

```
 "x" "y"
1 A text1
2 A text2
3 A text3
4 B text4
5 B text4
6 B text5
7 C text6
```

And I need to transform into this:

```
 "x" "y"    
1 A text1;text2;tex3
2 B text4;text5
3 C text6
```

Probably can be done with reshape or recast, but im not sure how to keep the texts values in the same row.
Thanks!

Comment: @thelatemail Good catch, the answer there is a bit more general (dealing with multiple columns).  The one answer that uses `paste(., collapse=";")` would likely answer this question.

Comment: Thanks both. Sometimes is difficult to put an idea from spanish to english and that conspire to do more difficult the search in the rest of the forum. I will try to be more careful next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(y= toString(y)), by = x]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dplyr` to do this as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

### Data is set from "dput" output.
data_xy <- structure(list(x = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"), y = c("text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text4", "text5", "text6")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
data_xy %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    summarise(y = paste(unique(y), collapse=";"))

##   x                 y
## 1 A text1;text2;text3
## 2 B       text4;text5
## 3 C             text6

## OR

data_xy %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(paste(unique(.), collapse=";")))
```

Since your output shows only one occurrence of `text4` for `B`, `unique` is used.